# Target command not found when target is embedded in included Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run GNU Make on a Makefile say Makefile1 that includes another Makefile2. Here is how Makefile1 looks like

```
include absolute_path to Makefile2


target_from_Makefile2: Dependencies
              run_target_from_Makefile2
```

and here is how Makefile2 looks like

```
run_target_from_Makefile2: Dependencies
     run_xyz
```

Here is the Error that I see

```
make: run_target_from_Makefile2: Command not found
Makefile1:5: recipe for target 'run_target_from_Makefile2' failed
make: *** [target_from_Makefile2] Error 127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format of a makefile is

```
targetFile: dependency1 dependency2 ...
        run_command_to_build_targetFile

dependency1:
        run_command_to_build_dependency1

dependency2:
        run_command_to_build_dependency2
```

Change your makefile 1 to be:

```
include absolute_path to Makefile2


target_from_Makefile2: Dependencies run_target_from_Makefile2
```

You should stop getting the error but the build process is a little unclear. Post some more definitive code if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks. I am running the Makefile. I will keep you posted as soon as it finishes. It will take 2 hours!!

Answer (score 3):

A make recipe is a shell script.  A shell is invoked and the text of the recipe is handed to the shell to run.  The name of a target in a makefile is not a shell script command, so you can't use it as a shell command to run.

You can either declare the other target a prerequisite:

```
target_from_Makefile2: Dependencies run_target_from_Makefile2
```

so that the target from makefile2 is a prerequisite, or you can use recursive make, like this (but in this case there's no point in including makefile2):

```
target_from_Makefile2: Dependencies
          $(MAKE) -f path_to_makefile2 run_target_from_Makefile2
```

Comment: could you answer this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411762/variable-name-expansion-not-working-inside-target-in-gnu-makefile#

Comment: could you check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613186/gnu-makefile-treating-each-recipe-line-as-sub-shell-command-without-continuation