# variable name expansion not working inside target in GNU Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory inside target based on a rule but for some reason the variable is not getting expanded i.e., $(OUT_DIR) is blank and mkdir -p does not work. Here is the code

```
target_%:  /home/user/%/.file : file.c
    export OUT_DIR = /home/user/$* ; \
    mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)     ;\
    .
    .
    .
```

After making the changes suggested by @Beta, here is how the code looks like

```
target_%:  /home/user/%/.file : file.c
    export OUT_DIR=/home/user/$* ; \
    mkdir -p $${OUT_DIR}     ;\
    cd $${OUT_DIR}           ; \
    ln -s /home/user/file1.c  file1.c.link ;\
```

When I run the code, i get the Error

```
/bin/sh: line 3:        : command not found
```

on `mkdir -p` command. I have played by removing `;\` and it works till `mkdir $${OUT_DIR}` and `cd $${OUT_DIR}` but i see the soft link created in the directory where the makefile is rather than in the OUT_DIR where it should be created.

I am also not sure when to use `\` vs `; \` vs `not using at all`. Any suggestion on that would be awesome

Comment: First, you should not have `;\\` at the end of your final line, else you'll combine that final line with whatever the next line is after this rule (what is it?).  Second, please show the entire output of make _particularly_ the commands it prints before you see the error message.  This error is from the shell, which means your shell commands are not well-formed, and make will print out exactly what it is asking the shell to run before it does so.  Also just make sure that there is no whitespace on any of your lines after the final backslash character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Make* variables and *shell* variables are not the same thing.

If you have something like `$(OUT_DIR)` in the makefile, Make will expand it, and since you haven't defined it in the makefile, it expands to nothing. Your rule then looks like:

```
target_%:  /home/user/%/.file : file.c
    export OUT_DIR = /home/user/$* ; \
    mkdir -p      ;\
    ...
```

If the command (`export ...`) you define `OUT_DIR` as a shell variable. The way to expand a shell variable in the shell is with '$', like this:

```
...$OUT_DIR ...
```

But '$' is a special character in Make, so to use it as you intend, you must *escape* is with another '$':

```
target_%:  /home/user/%/.file : file.c
    export OUT_DIR = /home/user/$* ; \
    mkdir -p $$OUT_DIR     ;\
    ...
```

Comment: can you write OUT_DIR with parentheses $$(OUT_DIR) ?

Comment: No, because then bash would try to interpret `$(OUT_DIR)`, which it would take to mean "run `OUTDIR`".   You could do `$${OUT_DIR}` and this would work.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry , thanks. I am getting this Error /bin/sh: line 1:        : command not found

Comment: @Beta I am running into this Error /bin/sh: line 1:        : command not found

Comment: @tulamba: Can you pare it down to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What happens when you try to execute that command on the command line, without Make?

Comment: @Beta. Added more explanation.