# GNU Makefile first target not getting invoked

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

I am following the solution in [GNU Makefile treating each recipe line as sub-shell command without continuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613186/gnu-makefile-treating-each-recipe-line-as-sub-shell-command-without-continuation)

```
target_compile: PROJECT_SIM_OPTS += -LDFLAGS -L${CURRENT_DIR},-lm -load

target_compile: copy_shared_object actual_compile_with_sim_opts
    @echo PROJECT_SIM_OPTS=${PROJECT_SIM_OPTS} ...
```

When I make the Makefile, I am able to see the second `target_compile` fire off but not the first `target_compile` which has no dependencies and recipe except a variable. I tried adding `override` before `PROJECT_SIM_OPTS` and `;` at the end of the line but still it is not working.

There is no Error message reported which makes it even harder to detect. In nutshell, I have to embed this piece of code in another Makefile and if the first target would work, I will see a file generated with `-LDFLAGS -L${CURRENT_DIR},-lm -load` in it. Since this file is being generated without these flags, I am confident to say that first target is not firing.

How can the two target_compile work together?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I get `PROJECT_SIM_OPTS=-LDFLAGS -L,-lm -load ...` Can you confirm that you get `PROJECT_SIM_OPTS= ...`? Which version of Make are you using?

Comment: @Beta. Thanks for your comment. Here is what I see for Make version `GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Comment: @Beta I confirm I see what you see. I am testing it in my actual makefile  which takes 40 minutes to compile.

Comment: Then comment out the time-consuming compiler command, and add an `echo PROJECT_SIM_OPTS=${PROJECT_SIM_OPTS}`. If that works, uncomment the compiler command but make sure the command itself is being echoed to the screen so that you can see what it actually is -- and interrupt the compilation, don't wait 40 minutes.

Comment: @Beta. I believe I have a clue. `PROJECT_SIM_OPTS` is a global variable earlier in an included makefile while in `target_compile`, which comes later, it is target specific variable. I see its value being printed in the file when `PROJECT_SIM_OPTS` is a global variable but not when it is target specific variable. Any idea how to make its behavior like a global variable even in a target scope?

Comment: Now I have no idea what you're trying to do. Target-specific variables and "global" variables behave *exactly the same way* within the target scope, so I don't know what it means to make one behave like the other in that scope. I suggest you post a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve).

Comment: @Beta Thanks for confirming that global variables behave exactly the same in the target scope. I will put the minimal complete example later

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an ordering issue. In my case

```
target_compile: copy_shared_object actual_compile_with_sim_opts
    @echo PROJECT_SIM_OPTS=${PROJECT_SIM_OPTS} ...
```

`actual_compile_with_sim_opts` was running before `copy_shared_object`

Once I put the dependency like this, 
`actual_compile_with_sim_opts: copy_shared_object`

I was able to get both targets to work with proper flags

Thanks  @Beta for all the help.